# Unexpected Behavior in Laravel 7 with Storage::put() and fopen()

Tags: laravel, file-upload, stream

I am working on a solo project where admin users will be able to manage Virtual Machines via a web application run on laravel 7. I am currently creating the creation controller which requires uploading large files (.ovas). I am trying to use streams (I think) in a store method.

Specifically, a view has a form with a standard file inclusion that sends the request to the controller. The form gets validated and then I try to move the file into storage as such:

```
    $data = $this->validator($request);

    Storage::put('files', fopen($data['file'], 'r+'));
```

Where $data['file'] is the uploaded file. I can see the file being uploaded locally (while monitoring hdd usage), but after it is sent, laravel returns the following error

**fopen(/var/www/html/devel/ocl/storage/app/files): failed to open stream: Is a directory**

The error seems pretty obvious, so I was curious and decided to return the *fopen()* call before storage to see if I could invoke the same error by changing the method to:

```
    $data = $this->validator($request);

    return var_dump(fopen($data['file'], 'r+'));
```

However, no error is invoked and I get **resource(8) of type (stream)** as expected (I think). The tmp resource disappears and no errors are thrown. I am a bit baffled on why this is occurring as I would assume that function call resolves before the storage. I feel like I'm missing something fundamental with PHP/laravel and cannot think of how to continue to explore the issue.

Why does the first call to fopen() seem to see $data['file'] as a path, but the second call to just fopen() work as intended? I am hoping the answer can help remedy the issue.

Thanks!

Comment: did you figure it out?